# Trouble with vwprintf/vswprintf on OS X

Tags: c, macos, printf

To give more detail I am writing the code using C for OS X using XCode 4.2 and the LLVM GCC 4.2.2 compiler.

I have a variable argument function - I include the entire function for completeness although I /believe/ most of it to be irrelevant, the only problem I have is with how vswprintf behaves in some cases.

```
void FTFRenderText( const struct FTFFont* const pxFont,
               const int iStartX, const int iStartY,
               const wchar_t* const wszFormatString,
               ... )
{
    if( !pxFont || !( pxFont->mbValid ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    static wchar_t lswszBuffer[ 2048 ];    
    va_list xArguments;
    va_start( xArguments, wszFormatString );
    //
    // SE - TODO: remove
    vwprintf( wszFormatString, xArguments );
    va_end( xArguments );
    va_start( xArguments, wszFormatString );
    //
    vswprintf( lswszBuffer, 2048, wszFormatString, xArguments );
    va_end( xArguments );
    const struct FTFTriList xTriList =
        FTFCreateTriListFromText( pxFont, iStartX, iStartY, lswszBuffer );

    const int iIndexCount = xTriList.miNumIndices;
    if( iIndexCount )
    {
        // SE - TODO: something to allow user selected colour
        glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
        glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, xTriList.mpfVertices );
        glDrawElements(
            GL_TRIANGLES, iIndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, xTriList.mpsIndices );
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am being dim but it seems that if I pass in a simple enough set of parameters like "Test %d", 101 the functions work fine. However if I pass in a string with a unicode character, either as a literal or using \uXXXX the string I get back from vswprintf is completely empty In the debugger I can see the the compiler has done the right thing with the string in memory, and it contains the unicode character - but the string written to by vswprintf is all 0s.

Comparing with wprintf and vwprintf is interesting - because both seem to behave as I expect and produce the expected unicode character from both a literal and the \uXXXX escaping.

I am loathe to suggest the library is buggy because a great number of other libraries and apps have been built on top just fine, so I think I am doing something wrong, but I just can't see what it could possibly be...

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the (variadic) string that you're passing in a `wchar_t` string, or a `char` string using (e.g.) UTF-8 or similar? … i.e. is the "string in memory" being stored multibyte?

Comment: So far I have only used literal wide strings, e.g. L"Test %d" - from inspecting memory the compiler seems to produce the correct wchar_t (32-bit) string of character codes

Comment: a copy-pasted example for exactness: FTFRenderText(&gxFont, 100, 500, L"%%" );

Comment: So the Unicode chars are in the format string, itself, not params to it (e.g. `FTFRenderText (font, x, y, L"%ls", L"你好，世界。")` vs. `FTFRenderText (font, x, y, L"這個數字是%d", 4)` … ? (apologies if Google Translate stuck anything rude in there…!)

Comment: Ouch. Sorry, I'm out of ideas :-) I was hoping for something along the usual lines of `%s` vs. `%ls` vs. bad pointers in the variadic, which would be unlikely here, but plausible. If you're passing in a format string with the content already in it, that line of questioning won't help… sorry. :-/

Comment: np. the problem occurs if i use unicode in the format string specifically.

Comment: Despite their claim in the string programming guide to follow the IEEE standard, they use 32-bit wchar_t and have %S interpreted as a 16-bit ucs2 string, this is a definite break from the standard.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wprintf.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

"If an l (ell) qualifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to an array of type wchar_t. "

I wonder if this is part of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

There was never answer, so let me at least provide the sloppiest one possible:

**Use UTF-8.**

All of the ansi string functions in OS X/iOS are actually utf-8 functions in disguise.